# Usercard Formatting Sometimes Clipped

Tags: bug, design

I noticed in a [AU post](https://askubuntu.com/q/441843/264589) today that a usercard was clipped on the right, cutting off the user's bronze-badges count:

[image: Clipped Ask Ubuntu Usercard]

Of course this clipping does not affect all usercards; most I have seen look fine.

Save your rotten tomatoes, but to the extent it may help in understanding the issue, I happened to be browsing the site with Chrome 33.0.1750.154 m on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit at the time.

Am I correct that this is a layout bug?

Comment: They weren't expecting anyone to have so many bronze badges ^^

Comment: I've seen this bug talked about on MSO before.  I'm having trouble finding the question, but I'm sure the answer was something like "Well that's a great problem to have isn't it?  If you have enough golds and silvers to push the bronzes off the edge, we already know how awesome you are."

Comment: It can't be reproduced in SO/MSO, so either will be fixed in the next build or something else.